# jQuery with Vue.js - $(this) is not working in method

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Firstly, I know that mixing jQuery with Vue is not a good idea. But still, I am trying to do something with an element after a click but `$(this)` doesn't work.

```js
methods: {
  openSMS() {
    $(this).hide(); // <-- not working here..
    // More code...
  },
  addEventListeners() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".ml-inbox-msg-item").click(function() {
        // $(this).hide() <-- it works here
        InboxSidebar.openSMS();
      });
    });
  }
}
```

There are many `.ml-inbox-msg-item` elements on a page.

If I put `$(this).hide()` inside the `.click` function then it works. Is there a way to pass it to the `openSMS()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the scope of `openSMS()` is not the same as the `click` handler function. Assuming you can change the method signature, modify `openSMS()` to accept the element reference as an argument:

```js
methods: {
  openSMS(el) {
    $(el).hide();
  },
  addEventListeners() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".ml-inbox-msg-item").click(function() {
        InboxSidebar.openSMS(this);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked! That's exactly what I was looking for!